# yum - install package forcing replacing files

Tags: yum, rpm

I want to install one package with yum and not using rpm but with the same behavior like `--replacefiles` in rpm. I have one package that have file conflicts with other and I need to install forcing with yum. This package is mine, so I can modify spec file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [trigger scriptlets](http://ftp.rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/triggers.html) for this.

For illustration, let's say that the file `/etc/contested` is owned by a rpm named `generally`, and you have another package (`specifically`) which wants to force-overwrite the same file.

In `specifically.spec`, you install the new version of the file to `%{_datadir}/%{name}/etc.contested`, and use this trigger scriptlet to install it to `/etc`:

`%triggerin -- generally
install -m 0644 %{_datadir}/%{name}/etc.contested %{_sysconfdir}/contested`

The scriptlet will be run every time that `generally` is installed or updated, as well as every time `specifically` is installed or updated.

RPM will still notice that the file isn't as it's expected to be, but it won't stop you from installing or uninstalling.

Comment: Thanks you very much. You helped me to fix 5 year long standing issue. Now I am no longer afraid of **yum update -y**

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify spec file maybe you can remove the files that conflict in the files section ?
Do you specify a folder in that section ? or file by file ?

Comment: But, this files are dependencies with other package, can one repo delete files that use other repo with yum?

Comment: I don't get you this time.
Why do you speak of repo ? This has no link with the package itself.
From what I understood you have at least 2 packages already installed that are "owning" at least a common file.
One of these 2 packages is already installed and you want to install the second one, which fails because the file is already owned by another package. But you can modify that last package.
In that case modify the spec file of that last package before you install and remove the conflicting file from the file section.

Comment: I need to overwrite the file, I can remove the conflict, I need to make effective the sustitution

Comment: Ah okay this wasn't clear, sorry for the bad answer then, I didn't get you right.
It seems there is no way with yum.